# How to dynamically import something from another file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

Say I have a first python file with a couple of dicts int it :

**FeatureBook.py**

```py
horse = {"legs": 4,
         "size": "large",
         }
chicken = {"legs": 2,
           "size": "small",
           }
```

And a second script in which I want to import one of these dictionaries depending on a variable. For example I want to do something like this:

```py
myAnimal = "horse"

from FeatureBook import myAnimal
```

But this wont work. I know I could just make the whole script a single dictionary and use animal names as keys to get nested dicts. But I'm curious if there is a simple way to do this? I have been searching around without finding anything that seems to fit this specific scenario.

Comment: But where is ```myAnimal``` in the file? Also, unless `small` is a variable, ```"size": 'small'``` `'small'` should be in quotes

Comment: HI Sujay, thanks fixed strings, But yes thats my point, Im trying to dynamically import from FeatureBook.py based on a parameter.

Comment: I'm pretty sure making imports like that is a sign of messy programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`importlib` will let you do this kind of dynamic imports:

```py
import importlib

feature_book = importlib.import_module("FeatureBook")
myAnimal = "horse"
animal = gettattr(feature_book, myAnimal)
print(animal)
```

Comment: Tbh in the question "FeatureBook" is not a variable, so you can simply do 

import FeatureBook
instead of
feature_book = importlib.import_module("FeatureBook")

Comment: Thank you @Seon !! that's exactly what i was looking for.